# Solving $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1\times3+3\times5+\dots+(2n-1)\times(2n+1)}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate
>   $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1\times3+3\times5+\dots+(2n-1)\times(2n+1)}{n^2}$ using Stolz-Cesaro theorem .

Now, my attempt is :( i am not sure if it is correct)

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n4k^2-1}{n^2}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{4\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1}{n^2}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-n}{n^2}$$

= ( and now i've applied the Stolz-Cesaro theorem)

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{4n(n+2)(2n+2)-6-4(n+1)(2n+1)+6}{6}}{n+1-n}$$

= (which, after jumping a few steps, lead me to the following answer)
 $$2(n-1)$$

Is this correct ?

Comment: Did you mean $(2n-1)\times(2n\color{red}+1)$ in the title and body?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will correct it right now

Comment: If this is correct, the the limit does not exist, but $2(n-1)$ is only the function describing the asymptotic behaviour. Is that a regularization how in "$1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$" ?

Comment: Done, now do you think my attempt is the correct one ?

Comment: Working out the expression gives $\frac13[4n+6-\frac1{n}]$. If $n\to\infty$ then this diverges to $+\infty$

Comment: So, nothing is being said in my book other than to solve this problem using Stolz-Cesaro theorem . Also, what i've posted is my attempt which i am not sure if it is correct, my book doesn't give the end result.

Comment: You give $2(n-1)$ as result of some limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$. But in such limit $n$ cannot have a place, because $n$ is a *ranging* variable.

Comment: Did you mean $n^3$ in the denominator?

Comment: I see, so i've looked again in my book and the problem initially looks like this : $a_n=\frac{1\times3+3\times5+\dots+(2n-1)\times(2n+1)}{n^2}$ and it says "Solve the following". I figured i should take the limit of it since this problem is at the lesson :  Stolz-Cesaro theorem

Comment: No, it is $n^2$

Comment: Then the limit is obviously $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let 
$$a_n = 1\times 3 + 3\times 5 + \cdots + (2n-1)\times(2n+1), b_n = n^2,$$
Then
$$\lim\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} = \lim\frac{(2n+1)(2n+3)}{(n+1)^2-n^2}=\infty.$$
So by [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), 
$$\lim\frac{1\times 3 + 3\times 5 + \cdots + (2n-1)\times(2n+1)}{n^2}=\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

It makes little sense to use the Cesaro theorem if you "know" that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

The point of the exercise is most likely to see that Stolz-Cesaro allows you to conclude without that information. Indeed:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n (4k^2-1)}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{4n^2-1}{n^2-(n-1)^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{4n^2}{2n}=+\infty$$